# "TypeError: hashpw() argument 1 must be str, not bytes" when trying to register a user with flask-security

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt, flask-security

I'm trying to create a small flask application using the [Enferno framework](http://enferno.io/), but when I try to register a user I get an error that seems to be generated by the passlib library. I can't understand if it's something I did or if it is an error in the library itself.

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
        response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 125, in dispatch_request
        return view_func(**req.view_args)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 205, in wrapper
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_security/views.py", line 117, in register
        user = register_user(**form.to_dict())
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_security/registerable.py", line 28, in register_user
        kwargs['password'] = encrypt_password(kwargs['password'])
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_security/utils.py", line 151, in encrypt_password
        return _pwd_context.encrypt(signed)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/context.py", line 2495, in encrypt
        return self._get_record(scheme, category).encrypt(secret, **kwds)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 558, in encrypt
        self.checksum = self._calc_checksum(secret)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 285, in _calc_checksum
        return self._calc_checksum_backend(secret)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 1458, in _calc_checksum_backend
        return self._calc_checksum_backend(secret)
    File "/home/el3k0n/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 333, in _calc_checksum_pybcrypt
        hash = _bcrypt.hashpw(secret, config)
TypeError: hashpw() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3, I would suggest filing a bugreport with flask-security perhaps.

Comment: This looks like it may be stemming from a known bug in passlib 1.6.2 and earlier.  Updating to passlib 1.6.4 (released on 2015-7-25) should fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this.  Turns out, I had installed both `bcrypt` and `python-bcrypt` in my virtualenv.  `passlib.hash.bcrypt` has a check to see which version on bcrypt is present.  By removing the `python-bcrypt`, I was able to cease this error from being thrown.

Comment: thanks, that helped me too ;) although I had to uninstall everything with bcrypt (bcrypt, python-bcrypt and flask-bcrypt)

Comment: I didn't have both `bcrypt` and `python_bcrypt` installed, only `python_bcrypt==0.3.2`. But when I switched to `bcrypt==3.1.7`, everything worked fine.